# Why does my tic tac toe minimax algorithm not work?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, minimax

Sorry to dump my code like this, but I've been pulling my hair out the last hours trying to figure out where my minimax algorithm in python is going wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
inf = 1000
bo = [["x", "o", "o"],
      [" ", "o", " "],
      [" ", "x", "x"]]    

def bestMove(board):
    bestScore = -inf
    bestMove = None
    for i in range(3):
       for j in range(3):
          if(board[i][j]==" "):
            board[i][j]=getTurn(board)
            score = minimax(board, searchdepth, True)
            board[i][j]=" "
            if score > bestScore:
                bestScore = score
                bestMove = [i, j]
print("\n\n\n")
return bestMove

searchdepth = 10
def minimax(node, depth, maxP):
    resultat = win(node)
    if resultat=="x": return 1
    if resultat=="o": return -1
    if resultat=="tie": return 0
    if depth == 0: return 0

if maxP==True:
    value = -inf
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if node[i][j] == " ":
                node[i][j] = getTurn(node)
                newval = minimax(node, depth - 1, False)
                node[i][j] = " "
                value = max(newval, value)
    return value
if maxP==False:
    value = inf
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if node[i][j] == " ":
                node[i][j] = getTurn(node)
                newval = minimax(node, depth - 1, True)
                node[i][j] = " "
                value = min(newval, value)
    return value
print(bestMove(bo))
```

Output: [1, 0]
Expected output: [2, 0]

Comment: Where would a value other than 1, -1, or 0 come from? Also, the indentation is broken in your question.

Comment: If I supply versions of `getTurn` and `win`, I get [2,0].  I'll post it below.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips about debugging your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always sending a 1 in case 'X' wins, this is not correct. This means that if it is O:s turn it will think it is good if X wins. The easiest way would be to give a different value depending on who's turn it is, that is give a score of 1 if YOURSELF win, -1 if OPPONENT wins and 0 if draw.

Answer (score 0):

I supplied versions of `getTurn` and `win`, since you didn't supply them, and I fixed the indentation problems below, and this prints out [2,0].

```
inf = 1000
bo = [[" ", " ", " "],
      [" ", " ", " "],
      [" ", " ", " "]]    

def getTurn(board):
    x = sum(n == 'x' for row in bo for n in row)
    o = sum(n == 'o' for row in bo for n in row)
    return 'x' if x == o else 'o'

def win(board):
    for i in range(3):
        if board[i][0]==board[i][1]==board[i][2] and board[i][0] != ' ':
            return board[i][0]
        if board[0][i]==board[1][i]==board[2][i] and board[0][i] != ' ':
            return board[0][i]
    if board[0][0]==board[1][1]==board[2][2] and board[0][0] != ' ':
        return board[0][0]
    if board[0][2]==board[1][1]==board[2][0] and board[0][2] != ' ':
        return board[0][2]
    if not any( n == ' ' for row in board for n in row ):
        return 'tie'
    return None

def bestMove(board):
    bestScore = -inf
    bestMove = None
    for i in range(3):
       for j in range(3):
          if(board[i][j]==" "):
            board[i][j]=getTurn(board)
            score = minimax(board, searchdepth, True)
            board[i][j]=" "
            if score > bestScore:
                bestScore = score
                bestMove = [i, j]
    return bestMove

searchdepth = 10

def minimax(node, depth, maxP):
    resultat = win(node)
    if resultat=="x": return 1
    if resultat=="o": return -1
    if resultat=="tie": return 0
    if depth == 0: return 0

    if maxP:
        value = -inf
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if node[i][j] == " ":
                    node[i][j] = getTurn(node)
                    newval = minimax(node, depth - 1, False)
                    node[i][j] = " "
                    value = max(newval, value)
    else:
        value = inf
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if node[i][j] == " ":
                    node[i][j] = getTurn(node)
                    newval = minimax(node, depth - 1, True)
                    node[i][j] = " "
                    value = min(newval, value)

    return value

while not win(bo):
    t = getTurn(bo)
    m = bestMove(bo)
    bo[m[0]][m[1]] = t

print(bo)
print("Result:",win(bo))
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for this specific configuration, however if you start with an empty board and let the ai play itself, it only plays the next immediate move. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, yes, if you want it to play a whole game, then you have to have a loop to play more than one move.  I've changed the script above.

Comment: Yes I understand that, however the algorithm just plays the next empty slot in the game every move. Is there something missing?

Comment: What are you expecting?  In each case, given your criteria, the best move is the next open square.  Tic-tac-toe is a stupid game.  There IS no "winning strategy".

Comment: Where in my criteria does it state that the next open square is best?

Comment: Your only criteria is, "does this move lead to a win?"  At the beginning of the game, every move potentially leads to a win, so it picks the first one.

Comment: @TimRoberts, this is not how minimax works, it will play the best move given the current board state. In Tic tac toe you can also get each possible outcome of the game so if there is a win the AI should play the move leading to it (given best possible play from the opponent).

Comment: @eligolf -- yes, but in his code "best possible play" only has three choices -- win, lose, or draw.  From that initial position, essentially all moves are equally good.

Comment: @TimRoberts, there are only 3 possible outcomes in tic tac toe. From the initial position the game is a draw given best play from both players, hence it will pick the first move you check. But later on it might be a different case.

Comment: Right, although you could conceivably derive a "score" that boosts quicker wins.  I'm not sure why you're arguing with me, I think we are saying the same thing.

Comment: Try creating two variables, perhaps named bot and player. Say bot="x" and player="o". If you alternate the values between them two in succession after each move and use the minimax function, it will generate the theoritcally best moves. Minimax doesn't just think "does this move lead to a win?", instead it returns the best possible response for each player, meaning that a move is only as good as the weakest link in the chain. It doesn't make any difference for board states with large tree structures, but it critical moments the minimax algorithm evaluates the best moves perfectly.

Comment: That would be true **IF** you were scoring the moves so that the moves with the quickest win scored higher, or the moves that blocked the most opponent moves scored higher, but that's NOT what you're doing.  There are no bonuses and no penalties.  Your score for ANY move is just the maximum of the three values  (-1, 0, 1).  From that first position, ANY move will lead to a win, so every cell is going to return a score of 1.  Thus, you pick the first open cell.